# Immersed principal subbundles

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, principal-bundles

In Kobayashi and Nomizu's *Foundations of Differential Geometry vol. 1* the authors define immersed principal subbundles (actually, they call them *imbeddings*) of a principal $G$-bundle $\pi: P \to M$ as a principal $G'$ bundle $\pi': P' \to M'$ with an injective immersion $f: P' \hookrightarrow P$ and an injective homomorphism of Lie groups $\phi: G' \hookrightarrow G$ such that 
$$
f(q \cdot g) = f(q) \phi(g) \quad \text{for all}~q \in P', g \in G'~.
$$
This induces a smooth map $h: M' \to M$ such that $h \circ \pi' = \pi \circ f$. The authors claim that (in the case of a immersed subbundle) this is also an injective immersion.

I don't see why the last statement should hold. Take for example $M' = \mathbb{R}$, $G' = \{e\}$, so $P' = \mathbb{R} \times \{e\}$ and $P = \{p\} \times \mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $M$ is a single point and $G = (\mathbb{R}^2, +)$. Then the map

\begin{align}
    \mathbb{R} \times \{e\} &\to \{p\} \times \mathbb{R}^2 \\
    (t, e) &\mapsto (p, (t, 0))
\end{align}

satisfies the conditions to be an immersed principal subbundle. However the map induced on $\mathbb{R} \to \{p\}$ is not an injective immersion. Am I  missing something (an additional assumption, a different definition)? If not, is there any  assumption that can be added to make the claim in the book true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're exactly correct. Their definition allows you to switch the rôle of base and fiber (you could have taken $G=\Bbb R$ instead of $\Bbb R^2$), which is clearly not what they intended. Of course, they were thinking of immersing $M'$ in $M$ and $G'$ in $G$, and your example shows that immersing $P'$ in $P$ certainly does not suffice. I suspect that in their applications they will have $M'$ immersing into $M$ in the first place. Can you chase down the appearance in the theory of connections to which they refer and edit your question?

Comment: Most of the time they actually even require $M' \to M$ to be a diffeomorphism.